# JPA query by Date range when date is INSTANT

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, instant

Spring data could resolve parameter of my method.
I have this method and receive

> Could not determine data type of parameter $1

`d.date` is a timestamp

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM DTO d WHERE d.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)                        

List<DTO> findAllByDateRange(@Param("startDate") Instant startDate, @Param("endDate") Instant endDate);
```

I've tried to cast it to timestamp but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `CAST(d.date as DateTime)` instead of `d.date`. This *should* guide the data-type of $1 and $2.